# How get time only prior 12:00 PM in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

```
let temp = dateFormatter.date(from: 2017-10-10 23:34:00)
```

how to identify if `temp` before `12:00 PM` of after `12:00 PM`

Comment: in a 24 hours clock if the hour is in range of _{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}_ marks an AM time while the range of _{12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}_ could considered as PM. piece of cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
let temp1 = dateFormatter.date(from: 2017-10-10 23:34:00)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "a"
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

let temp2 = dateFormatter.string(from: temp1)

if(temp2.contains("AM")){
     // your function
}else{
     // your function
}
```

Comment: you could just use "a" as format if that's all you need

Comment: how can I execute function if a equals a.m

Comment: I mean you dont need "hh:mm"

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)
```

and check if `hour >= 12` to know that it is 12PM or later.

Comment: You can shorten this a bit further to `Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)`, but this is the right answer — there's no reason to re-format the date and search for something in the output.

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to use `Date formatter` and `Calendar` which each user has defined in his own device. In this case you can present date like this:

```
let nowTime = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar.current
let time = dateFormatter.string(from: nowTime)
print(time) // output -- 12:14:32 PM
```